# Check If a sublist contains a sepecific object

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a list That contains sublists of Objects like shown Below

```
[[Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel', Instance of 'messageIdModel'], [Instance of 'messageIdModel']]
```

now I want to check that whether these sublists contains a specific MessagIdModel Object

```
messageIdModel toSearch=messageIdModel(messageId: snapshot.data[index].message_id);
```

I tried Achieving it using code shown below but it always returns empty result but the object exists in one of the sublists

```
mainList.where((element) => element.contains(toSearch))
```

Answer (score 0):

because these lists are nested you have to enter them two times. using a for loop it will be something like this:

```
for(var lst in mainList) {
for (var l in lst) {
l.contains(toSearch) // put whatever u wanna check here 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any instead of where:

```
var boolResult = mainList.any((element) {
      return element == toSearch;
    });
```